# A sequence $x_n$ defined inductively by $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$. Suppose $x_n\to x$ as $n\to \infty$ and $F'(x)=0$. Show $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=o(x_{n+1}-x_n)$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Let a sequence $x_n$ be defined inductively by $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$. Suppose that $x_n\to x$ as $n\to \infty$ and $F'(x)=0$. Show that $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=o(x_{n+1}-x_n)$.

I'm not sure how to do this. Any solutions are greatly appreciated. I think The Mean-Value Theorem will be useful and we can assume that $F$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: hint: $x_{n+2} - x_{n+1} = F(x_{n+1}) - F(x_n)$

Comment: @user251257 I have a small doubt. I have been trying to solve the problem, and stuck at the end. I am not able to understand how to get $o(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ from $o(x_{n+1}-x)-o(x_n-x)$.

Comment: it is easier if you expand around $x_n$ and use the integral version of the reminder ($C^1$ is useful here).

Comment: @user251257 I see what you did there. So I need to show that there exists a sequence $\epsilon_n\geq 0$ such that $|F(x_{n+1})-F(x_n)|\leq \epsilon_n |x_{n+1}-x_n|$? Is this where The Mean-Value Theorem can be used?

Comment: @DerpMagoo: yes. With $\epsilon_n \to 0$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=o(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ in a certain case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27784/proving-that-x-n2-x-n1-ox-n1-x-n-in-a-certain-case)

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct consequence of the mean value theorem and the assumption that $F$ is continuously differentiable (without this assumption the result may not hold).

We have via mean value theorem $$x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=F(x_{n+1})-F(x_{n})=(x_{n+1}-x_{n})F'(c)$$ for some $c$ between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$. As $n\to\infty$ we can see that both $x_{n} $ and $x_{n+1}$ tend to $x$ and therefore so does $c$. By continuity of $F'$, the value $F'(c) \to F'(x) =0$ and thus we have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $F'\in C^1$, we have:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-x_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{F(x_{n+1})-F(x_n)}{x_{n+1}-x_n}=F'(x)=0$

Where the last equality has ben obtained by the fact that the sequence is a cauchy sequence (since converges to $x$), and thus:

$\forall m \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{m+n} \to x_n$

Comment: @gabrielecassese This succession is of cauchy because it is convergent? And why can I ensure the last inequality if it is a succession of cauchy?

Comment: I think you have problem relating the limit with $F'(x) $. This is not true in general, but it holds when $F$ is continuously differentiable at $x$ and may fail if its not the case.

Comment: @user402543 yes, since it is convergent to x, it must be cauchy

Comment: @ParamanandSingh In fact, but the hypotesis of the continuous differentiability was given in the question

Comment: @gabrielecassese: even with assumption of continuous differentiability of $F$ one needs to apply mean value theorem. The way the equations are written they are missing some steps.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The mean value theorem is a corollary from the definition of the derivatives, I'm not seeing where there are missing passages

Comment: @gabrielecassese: mean value theorem is deep result requiring completeness of real numbers and it is definitely not a corollary of definition of derivatives. You should see my answer where I have used the mean value theorem and then applied limit (and also used continuity of $F'$ to get that limit as $0$).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I've already seen your answer (and I meant "corollary" as an implication of the frechet' derivative definition on an Hilbert space. To be precise, the mean value inequality is the corollary, I apologize for my mistake), but I cannot see where it is being more precise. I think I'm missing a point: where are the passages missing in these answer? Would you please be so kind as to explain those with some counterweamples? Thanks in advance

Comment: @gabrielecassese : since $x_n\to x$ it follows by definition of derivative that $(F(x_n) - F(x)) /(x_n-x) \to F'(x) $ and the same equation holds if $n$ is replaced by $x_{n+1}$. But from these it is not obvious (and neither guaranteed) that the ratio $(F(x_{n+1})-F(x_n))/(x_{n+1}-x_n)\to F'(x) $ as written in the answer. This must be demonstrated with some further analysis which uses continuity of $F'$.

Comment: @gabrielecassese: For a counter-example consider $F(x) =1/\lfloor x^{-2}\rfloor$ if $x\neq 0$ and $F(0)=0$. Then $F'(0)=0$ but $F'$ is not continuous at $0$. Next consider $x_n=(n-n^{-1})^{-1/2}$ if $n$ is odd and $x_n=n^{-1/2}$ if $n$ is even. Then you can see that the ratio $(F(x_{n+1})-F(x_n))/(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ does not tend to a limit.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How can you then prove that equality formally?

Comment: @user402543: I have shown the way in my answer.